# How to make a @JSONProperty with a dynamic value?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have  the following JSON output that I want to generate.

```
**JSON Output:**
{
  "ingredients": {
    "main": ["flour", "water", "egg"],
    "optional": ["olives", "salami"]
  }
}
```

I tried to create the following classes but I am having some difficulty to do the following:

1. How to create a dynamic JSONProperty, as in "main" and "optional"
   can be dynamic values.
2. How to return an array of Strings?
3. Am I even doing it the right way??

   ```
     public class Pizza {
         private Ingredients[] fIngredients;

         @JsonProperty("ingredients")
         public Ingredients[] getIngredients() { return fIngredients; }

         public void setIngredients(Ingredients ingredients) { fIngredients = ingredients; }
       }

       public class Ingredients {
         private String[] fFoods;

         @JsonProperty("????") // how do i put a dynamic name here?
         public String[] getFoods() { return fFoods; }

         public void addFoods(List<String> foodsList) {
           String[] array = foodsList.toArray(foodsList.size());
               fFoods = ArrayUtils.addAll(fFoods, array);
         }
       }
   ```

Comment: For starters you're not going to be able to use annotations to do it - you're likely going to need to grab an instance of ObjectMapper and do some manual processing steps to provide the dynamic JSON.

Comment: why you need dynamic name? can you use List<String> fFoods?

Answer (score 1):

In order to have dynamic properties, you can use `Map` type for your properties. So you can have your code like this:

```
public class Pizza {
    private Map<String, List<String>> ingredients = new HashMap();

    public Map<String, List<String>> getIngredients() {
        return ingredients;
    }

    public void addIngredient(String name, List<String> values) {
        ingredients.put(name, values);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pizza pizza = new Pizza();
        pizza.addIngredient("main", Arrays.asList("flour", "water", "egg"));
        pizza.addIngredient("optional", Arrays.asList("olives", "salami"));

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(pizza));
    }
}
```